# JQuery detect pagename and apply class to li

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I need to add a class to an li.
I first created the list and then I wasn't sure how to apply the class if a certain page came up (the page this list menu loads onto), so I tried playing with some code I saw somewhere. My question is: how do I get the class to apply to the element...it is suppose to highlight the text in the menu on that page. I figured I had to detect the page, and then apply the class. I also added the script to the bottom of the HTML so that it would read through the code first. If this is not making sense, please feel free to change it. I can't get it to work. I'm getting confused so I expect people to tell me it looks like that. I won't be surprized. So here's what I coded (
(I don't quite know what I'm doing):

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').prepend('<fieldset class="title"><legend>Menu</legend>'); 
    $('#menu').append('<li><a href="sdfsdf.html">sdfsd</a></li>');  
    $('#menu').append('<li><a href="sdfsdfs.html">sdfsdfdsf</a></li>');  
    $('#menu').append('<li><a href="#">sdfsdfsdf</a></li>');  
    $('#menu').append('<li><a href="#">sdfsdfdsf</a></li>');  
    $('#menu').append('<li><a href="#">sdfsdfsdf</a></li>');  
    $('#menu').append('<li><a href="#">sdfsdfsdf</a></li>');  
    $('#menu').append('<li><a href="#">sdfsdfds</a></li>');  
    $('#menu').append('<li><a href="#">sdfsdffsd</a></li>');  
    $('#menu').append('</fieldset>'); 

   var url = "nHSC.html"; 

        $('#menu li [0]').each(function(){
            alert(location.pathname);
           var myHref= $(this).attr('href');
           if( url == myHref) {
                $('#menu li [0]').addClass('#menu .current a');
           }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to add something in php to your script. Would be better. In my opinion.

Comment: That's not how work jQuery `append/prepend` methods: `$('#menu').prepend('<fieldset class="title"><legend>Menu</legend>');...$('#menu').append('</fieldset>');`

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#menu li').each(function(){
        alert(location.location);
       var myHref= resolve($(this).attr('href'),window.location);
       if( myHref== window.location) {
            $(this).addClass('.current');
            //return;
       }
    });
```

resolve function

```
 function resolve(url, base_url) {
var doc = document
, old_base = doc.getElementsByTagName('base')[0]
, old_href = old_base && old_base.href
, doc_head = doc.head || doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
, our_base = old_base || doc_head.appendChild(doc.createElement('base'))
, resolver = doc.createElement('a')
, resolved_url
;
our_base.href = base_url;
resolver.href = url;
resolved_url = resolver.href; // browser magic at work here

if (old_base) old_base.href = old_href;
else doc_head.removeChild(our_base);
return resolved_url;
 }
```